# C# 2D Array Match and Return 1 Dimension

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, match, do-while

I have a 2D array of strings in the format of [Name, Code] where Code is a single capitalized letter. I want to return all the 'Names' in the array based on a match of the 'Code', to increase the complexity I need to do it based on user input until a sentinel value is entered.

Example: array = [Fred, X],[Bryan, Y],[Angus,X], User Input is 'X', want to return Fred and Angus. My attempt -

```
        string CodeInput;
        const string STOP = "999";

        Write("\nEnter a Code or 999 to stop >> ");
        CodeInput = ReadLine();

        do
        {
            for (int Name = 0, Code =1; Name < array.GetLength(0); Name++)
            {
                if (CodeInput == array[Name,Code])
                {
                    for (int NameB = 0; NameB < array.GetLength(0); NameB++)
                        WriteLine(array[NameB, 0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Write("\nIncorrect code");
                }
                Write("\nEnter a Code or 999 to stop >> ");
                CodeInput = ReadLine();
            }
        }
        while (CodeInput != STOP);
    }
```

Results on a match lists all Names, not just matching. I understand why it isn't working - that the first array loop finds a match and the second then just spits out all names - but I have no idea how to make it work. Yes it is homework, I would love to be able to use a dictionary instead of arrays but not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Array declaration is missing in your sample code... It is 2D based on your own choice, or is it based on homework requirement? In the first case, I would re-declare as an array of pairs (maybe custom struct or KeyValuePair<,>); in the latter case, some information is missing, because then, I don't understand how you can use the Code as a key.

Comment: It's a sample of a larger piece of code and I missed the inclusion of the declaration sorry. 2D array was a requirement unfortunately (or arrays of any type but I've committed to 2d by now, in retrospect a poor decision?)

Comment: Why 2D? do you have data that is indexed by 2 different, unrelated, keys? an example of such indexing is a chess/checkerboard, where you have a number index and a letter index and their combination point to a single tile where you find your unique object (the game piece). Note that in a checkerboard all index keys are unique. Instead, in your explanation, the "X" and "Y" seem more like attributes (i.e. last names of persons or floors of a building where you can find several individuals), that can be used to find items but are not to uniquely identify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second **for** cycle spits out all names, because it's precisely what you're ask him to do.

```
for (int NameB = 0; NameB < array.GetLength(0); NameB++)

   WriteLine(array[NameB, 0]);
```

Is equivalent of displaying all names.

What you want to do is:

```
do
{
    // Flag to indicate that you've found at least one match.  
    bool isFound = false;
    for (int Name = 0, Code = 1; Name < array.GetLength(0); Name++)
    {
        if (CodeInput == array[Name, Code])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array[Name, 0]);
            isFound = true;
        }
    }
    // If no matches found - display message 
    if (!isFound)
    {
        Console.Write("\nIncorrect code");
    }
    // Moved out of cycle, so it won't be asked every iteration.
    Console.Write("\nEnter a Code or 999 to stop >> ");
    CodeInput = Console.ReadLine();
}
while (CodeInput != STOP);
```